# how do I access this pivot field

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to access a pivot field like so:

```
$attendee_waitlisted->pivot('order_number')
```

but I receive this error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::pivot()

In my View, I form `$attendee_waitlisted` like so:

```
{{$attendee_waitlisted = $program->waitlist->attendees->find($attendee)}}
```

I can see my `order_number` field in my HTML Output:

```
{
    "id":"24",
    "created_at":"2015-06-23 12:53:16",
    "updated_at":"2015-06-26 14:49:15",
    "first_name":"Abby",
    "last_name":"Gordon",
    "birthday":"2009-01-27",
    "media_release":"1",
    "food_consent":"1",
    "food_allergies":"",
    "special_care":"Paid first week",
    "user_id":"21",
    "contact_name":"",
    "contact_phone":"",
    "contact_email":"",
    "pivot":{
            "waitlist_id":"1",
            "attendee_id":"24",
            "created_at":"2015-08-11 18:42:37",
            "updated_at":"2015-08-11 18:56:43",
            "order_number":"1"
    }
}
```

**How do I access just that field?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access pivot fields as follows:

```
$attendee_waitlisted->pivot->order_number
```

Comment: So it was working...from home but at work now I am getting an error..`Trying to get property of non-object` on the same line of code. I didn't change anything so not sure why this is happening.

Comment: my bad,  I was getting this error because I had the statement in a `@foreach` loop so it was giving me an error for the other model instance that didn't have a waitlist pivot attached.